# why 'pip install mysqlclient' not working in ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have just created a virtual environment on my machine (I am running on ubuntu 18.04 LTS). I have the python version of 3.6.7 and now I want to install mysqlclient into my virtual environment.

After I do `pip install mysqlclient` it didn't work, instead it gave me errors saying;

> Command "python.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-zd21vfb3/mysqlclient/', and that the msql_config file is not found.

My setup tools are all up to date.

Comment: Looks like the system doesn't have mysql. `mysql_config` is a system config file relating to the local mysql server.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`mysqlclient` has a dependency on the mysql client & dev packages being installed.  In order to fix this on ubuntu, you have to use `apt-get` to install a couple of mysql packages.

In your case, it looks like the missing `mysql_config` might be missing on your system.  You can fix that by installing `libmysqlclient-dev` on ubuntu bionic.

Answer (score 13):

In order to correctly install MySQLClient on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 LTS you need to install each of the following:

```sh
# Replace python3.6 with which ever version of Python3 you are using
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev 
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

The last one is often missed on answers but is required now.

Only then can  you install it via pip. Also make sure to update pip so you are not using version 9 if that installs into your vevn.

Comment: This answer is working perfectly in my case, the Last step is important

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error when building my docker container. I tried installing the following in sequence but did not work.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

**Then this  solved the problem.**

```
sudo apt-get install default-libmysqlclient-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have already installed **setuptools**.
After that
in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Then(Keeping in mind to activate the ***virtual*** enviroment)

```
sudo pip3 install mysqlclient
```