# Linux Ubuntu 18.04 - Error loading MySQLdb module. Did you install mysqlclient?

Tags: mysql, django, linux, django-rest-framework, mysql-python

I'm getting the following error message while running my Django REST project with MySQL database in pipenv.

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

This seems like a very common problem (please don't mark as duplication), but after trying all the possible solutions I'm still getting the same issue..

A few things I tried:

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
pip3 install python3.6-dev 
pip3 install mysql-client
pip3 install libsqlclient-dev
pip3 install libssl-dev
```

What could still be the problem?

It's a Linux Ubuntu 18.04 server with Plesk. Python version 3.8.

Comment: Did you try to install `pip install pymysql`?

Comment: did you try this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53641541/why-pip-install-mysqlclient-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts/53641741

Comment: Rather that making us guess what you tried, could you be more specific than "trying all the possible solutions".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install this.

```
sudo apt install libpython3.8-dev
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 3):

`mysqlclient` has a dependency on the mysql client & dev packages being installed. In order to fix this on ubuntu, you have to use `apt-get` to install a couple of mysql packages.

In your case, it looks like the missing `mysql_config` might be missing on your system. You can fix that by installing `libmysqlclient-dev` on ubuntu bionic.

**another way**

install the follwing packages.

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev 
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
sudo apt-get install libsqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

other method

```
pip install pymysql
```

Then, edit the **init**.py file in your project origin dir(the same as settings.py)

add:

```
import pymysql

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should install **libmysqlclient-dev**: `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`

Comment: i did: `apt-get install mysqlclient*` my django 4.x installation and migration failed on python3.9 on debian 11. but code above fixed issue :/ note: i'm on mariadb 10.6.x